# Bootstrap form with fixed column width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an inline form with the following code:

```
<div class="card" style="width:100%;">
<div class="card-block">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                <label for="displayName">Display Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="displayName" style="height:30px;" id="displayName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
                <label for="officeEmail">Office Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="officeEmail" style="height:30px;" id="officeEmail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
   </div>  
</div>
```

when I run it it looks like this:
[image]

When I resize the Browser it's looking like this:
[image]

My question is how I can have input fields with fixed width and fixed distance between columns?

Thanks

Comment: Whoever just down voted my question please explain why.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="card" style="width:100%;">
<div class="card-block">

    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <label for="displayName">Display Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="displayName" style="height:30px;" id="displayName">
            </div>
            <div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <label for="officeEmail">Office Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="officeEmail" style="height:30px;" id="officeEmail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
   
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like. Will give it a try and update your answer status. Thanks

Comment: It works close. But still when I make browser smaller widths of fields get smaller too. https://jsfiddle.net/okgmn0ss/1/

Comment: you want to make the textbox size to be same or it can change based on your browser window size? if yes then you have to write media query for your textbox size which keeps on changing when you resize browser.

Comment: I want to keep boxes to their original size.

Comment: then you can give css of `width:100% !important` to textbox.